# Sum array in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to sum up the greyscale pixel values of a greyscale image "1.jpg" for each vertical columns of pixels in the image.

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("1.jpg", 0)
for i in range (img.shape[0]):
        aaa = img[i]
        print aaa
```

Doing this i get something like

```
aaa = [1,2,3] [2,3,4] [3,4,5] [4,5,6] .....
```

Now how do I sum up the array to get:

```
bbb = [6, 9, 12, 15, ....]
```

If I do:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("1.jpg", 0)
for i in range (img.shape[0]):
        aaa = img[i]
        bbb = sum(aaa, 0)
        print bbb
```

I get:

```
6
9
12
15
.
..
...
```

but thats not what I need !!!

---

**UPDATE : Solved**

Was finally able to do it by this:

```
import cv2
bbb = []
img = cv2.imread("1.jpg", 0)
for i in range (img.shape[0]):
        bbb.append(sum(img[i]))
```

Comment: Why are you printing the `bbb` result, just create an empty list and append the `bbb` to it at each iteration and after the for loop ends, just print the whole `list`

Comment: Thanks @ZdaR for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
you should put aaa in a container, like a list or set
aaa = []
for i in range (img.shape[0]):
        aaa.append(img[i])
        print aaa
```

or

```
aaa = [ i for i in range (img.shape[0])]


aaa = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6]]
[sum(a)for a in aaa]
```

out:

```
[6, 9, 12, 15]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Was finally able to do it by this:

`import cv2`
`bbb = []`
`img = cv2.imread("1.jpg", 0)`
`for i in range (img.shape[0]):`
`        bbb.append(sum(img[i]))`

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way among all answers perhaps, try using the numpy package side by side. as follows :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('your_image_file')
sum_cols = np.sum(img,axis=1)
sum_cols = np.sum(img,axis=1) #if the image is a color image.
```

This works, and sums along the second axis, ie the column sum for each row and each color channel.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it (untested). Note that `img.shape[1]` gives the number of image columns.

```
import cv2
results = []
img = cv2.imread('1.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
for col in range(img.shape[1]):
    results.append(sum(img[col]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get array like :

```
[1,2,3]
[2,3,4]
[3,4,5] 
[4,5,6]
```

then to sum up the array and to store it into a different list, try this code:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("1.jpg", 0)
final_list = []
for i in range (img.shape[0]):
    final_list.append(reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, img[i]))
print final_list
```